# Testing Child Component That pass State Up to Another Component

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a child component that lifts state up to a parent component in order to make it render a modal. Is it possible to use React Testing Library to check whether the modal has renderd from the parent component when the test is using the child component?

Comment: It sounds like that responsibility lies with the parent component: IMHO that should be included in the test for the parent component instead. Otherwise, you can just render the child component in a dummy parent component, and then you can check for whatever behavior it needs to trigger in the parent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are testing child component, then your testing library won't even know the existence of parent component. In this case you can verify whether your child component currently setting the state or not.

For parent component you have to test the parent component with particular state.